# Python Selenium cant locate iframe - gmail account generator

Tags: python, selenium, iframe, gmail, element

I hope you all feel well. I tried coding an "gmail creator".
This Project is really important to me, so I would be very
thankfull if someone can help me. If u want, for the guy who
can help me and if this works will get some money on paypal.
Not much but some money. Also sorry for my english I am from germany.
So :
I am struggling for 4.5 Hours now.
It just cant find the element "firstname". I tried via normal way:
driver find element by xpath and doesnt find, also id and many things.
Then I noticed, that there is an iframe on the page, so i though I have to switch to it before.
But now it cant find this iframe.

Infos:
-Python
-Selenium
-Chrome webdriver

THE SITE:
https://www.google.com/intl/de/gmail/about/#

CODE:

```
def main():
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument("--window-size=950,1000")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
    driver.get("https://www.google.com/intl/de/gmail/about/#")
    time.sleep(randint(1, 3))
    #click create account
    while True:
        try:
            driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div[4]/ul[1]/li[3]/a").click()
            break
        except:
            yeet = 1
    #works all well till here
  
    #now I am struggling finding element, firstname element  
    #firstname_input = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/form/span/section/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/input")
    #iframe = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/iframe")
    #iframe = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("iframe")
    #driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)

    ###all didnt work  

main()
```

Comment: I see no `firstname` there. Should I click on Create account button?

Comment: go to the site and then click "create account"

Comment: This is what I did. It opens a new window for me. For you too?

Comment: yea it does but then selenium cant find the element "firstname", like I mean where you input your firstname

Comment: OK, I understand. Will give you an answer in a second

Answer (score 1):

By clicking on "Create Account" button a new window is opened.
So, you have to switch to that new window.
To do so you should do the following:

```
new_window = driver.window_handles[1]
driver.switch_to_window(new_window)
```

Now you can access the "firstname" element and all the others there.
If you wish finally get back to the first window just do it similarly to the above:

```
initial_window = driver.window_handles[0]
driver.switch_to_window(initial_window)
```

Also, please never use long absolute locators like `"/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div[4]/ul[1]/li[3]/a`.
The 'Create Button' can be located by this `//li/a[@data-action="create an account" and (contains(@class,'button'))]` XPath

Comment: Yes you're right. Even though there's an iframe on the page that element is not inside it, a new window has opened.

Comment: Thanks, I will try and let u know then :)

Comment: @C.Peck OK, I checked the relevant element, not the entire page, you are right

Comment: It worked for me, Thanks, You can give me your paypal :)

Comment: Well, it's not working so here, but if you wish you are welcome to contact me on facebook https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100011831197069 (real mensch)

Comment: You can also accept my answer here. It will give me some virtual points :)

Comment: @Juluis_Python_2021 you promised to pay. OK, I didn't ask for money, but you even not accepted the answer